# Skip key from hash loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am performing an operation on hash values, lets say :

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
```

I am executing an `each` loop on `hash` but I want to skip keys `b` and `c`. I don't want to delete these from `hash`.

I have tried:

```
hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil}
hash.except(:c)
{ a: true, b: false, c: nil}
```

But it is not working. I am using `ruby 2.4.2`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your code that's *"not working"*. What do you mean by "not working"? `hash.except(:c)` returns `{:a=>true, :b=>false}`, as I'd expect. However, note that `Hash#except` is a method added by `ActiveSupport` (i.e. part of Rails), not core ruby.

Comment: sorry, I was testing it in irb, thanks now `except` is working in rails console

Comment: Since you actually wanted to skip `:c` *and* `:b`, you could do: `hash.except(:b, :c)`. Or maybe what you actually want (since the values for `:b` and `:c` are `false` and `nil` respectively) is something like: `hash.keep_if { |k, v| v }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `hash.except(:c)` returns `{ a: true, b: false }` as expected. Since you're using `Rails` it should work. The only subtle moment, that I want to take a note on is that:

```
hash.except([:b, :c])
```

won't work. You need to use

```
hash.except(:b, :c)
```

instead.

For general solution you need to use splat operator:

```
keys = [:b, :c]
hash.except(*keys)
```

Comment: Awesome , works smoothly. I like the way you use splat operator keeping it more generic.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply need to skip it while looping over the hash pairs, I personally would steer clear of using `except`, and use the uglier `next if key == whatever` within the loop.

A equality check between symbols is cheap, about the the most low overhead thing that can be done in Ruby, the basic equivalent of comparing two integers or booleans.

`except` on the other hand is not, especially as the size of the hash grows. You are creating a new cloned hash, minus the specified values, every time you call it. Even with a small hash, you are creating a new object needlessly.

I understand that many Ruby users are forever in pursuit of the "one-liners" or absolute shortest amount of code possible, I am guilty of it myself, but it needs done mindfully of whats going on beneath the surface, or you are creating less efficient code, not more.

So although not as "pretty", this would be more efficient:

```
hash.each do |k, v|
  next if k == :b || k == :c
   # Do stuff
end
```

**EDIT**

I was curious of the performance difference between what I was stating, and the use of `except`, and the resulting differences are significant.

First, I added the source for `except`, I didn't have Rails installed. This is straight from the source code from `activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb`.

```
class Hash

  def except!(*keys)
    keys.each { |key| delete(key) }
    self
  end

  def except(*keys)
    dup.except!(*keys)
  end
end
```

Then I did some benchmarking. I figured a 1,000,000 samples was enough for one run.

```
require 'benchmark'

hash = { a: true, b: false, c: nil }
count = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|

  bm.report("except") do

    count.times do
        hash.except(:b, :c).each do |k, v|
          # Do nothing
        end
    end
  end

  bm.report("next") do

    count.times do
      hash.each do |k, v|
        next if k == :b || k == :c
        # Do nothing
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running various times, including changing to `bmbm` to confirm the GC isn't skewing anything:

```
           user     system      total        real
except  1.282000   0.000000   1.282000 (  1.276943)
next    0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.246193)
```

On average, the use of `next` resulting in over 5x faster code. This difference grows even more the larger the hash becomes.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably just do something like this

```
my_hash = hash.reject { |k, _| %i[a b].include?(k) }

my_hash.each do |k, v|
  # Do what you need to and be free from worry about those pesky :a and :b keys
end
```